# React router causes invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React application that uses `react-router`. A minimalistic version of my routing is as follows:

```
<Router>
   <div className="App">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="app-container">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={Home} />
          <Route path="/logs" exact render={Logs} />
          <Route path="/log/:logID" exact render={Log} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
   </div>
</Router>
```

However, whenever I access a route that contains a React hook, my application crashes with the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://.../react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I am able to bypass this by entering a function like `render={() => <Log />}` into the `Route` component, but doing so makes me unable to access `match.params` in the component. Is there a fix that would allow me to use `render={Log}` without the error being thrown?

Edit:

Below is an example of a `Home` component that would crash the app:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

    const [foo, setFoo] = useState('bar');

    return (
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
    )
}
```

The error gets thrown when `useState` is called. The same behaviour would be observed for any other react hooks.

Comment: Can you include the `Home` component?

Comment: @TasosBu Edited my post to include an example

Answer (score 2):

From react-router docs:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
> router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
> children prop (below).

You really don't want to mount your routed component every time your parent is re-rendered. I'd suggest passing the component as a child - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

Comment: Yeah this is why I'm reluctant to use a function. I'm now passing the component in as a child and calling ```useParams``` - but any idea why does the ```render={component}``` syntax crash the app?

Comment: Based on Route code (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js) my best guess is that react doesn't see the component you pass in render as an actual component, but a function that generates some markup code. It makes sense then to get the error you get, because your hook will not be called inside you component, but in the Route component, reason why it won't be called at every render.